# How do you keep a JOIN table performant?

Tags: sql, linq

I'm drawing up plans for a few new features on my site, and one could be "solved" using a join table.

Example schema:

### Person table

- PK PersonId
- Name
- Age ...

### PersonCheckin table

- PK FK PersonId
- PK FK CheckinId
- Date ...

### Checkin table

- PK CheckinId
- CheckedInto ...

A join would be run to get the check in data for a person (connected by the PersonCheckin table). Since every person could check in an unlimited number of times, the PersonCheckin table could become very large.

I'd imagine this would cause some performance issues. What are typical ways this is handled to keep performance high?

Comment: I see that you're using a multi-column primary key. Be aware that the order of the columns (in the key) matters!

Comment: @David B: thanks for the heads up. What scenarios should I look out for, where the order of the columns matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join is considering the best performing means of connecting related tables.
But it really depends on the query, because it might not need to be a JOIN -- JOINing can inflate the record set on the parent tables side if there are more than one child record related, which means there could be a need for either GROUP BY or DISTINCT.  EXISTS or IN is a better choice in such situations...

Indexes can help on the column(s) used in the JOIN criteria, on both sides of the relationship.  In this example both sides are primary keys, which typically have the best index automatically created when the primary key is defined...

Comment: Since the PersonId and the CheckinId are the PK, they'd be in a clustered index, correct? The joins would be based on those ids. Would this be performant even when there are hundreds of thousands of entries in the join table?

Comment: @Chad: On SQL Server, yes.  Databases deal in upwards of billions of rows - I think you're bordering on premature optimization.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - ya, I'm not optimizing yet... just want to be aware of the limitations of this technique before I dive into using it as a solution. Thanks for the info, helps a lot!

Comment: @pst thanks, in this case would the clustered index be enough?

Comment: @Chad: clustered index > non-clustered index; you can only have one clustered index per table, typically (but not always) on the primary key.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks... will stick with this as the solution then. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to execute this query very often and you want to achieve better performance just create a view on the database where you write the join query

Comment: ...which may or may not result in better performance... in any case it doesn't address the underlying requirement for a good join: proper indexes

Comment: A view is just a prepared SQL statement - there's no performance benefit to using a non-materialized view.

Comment: Hmm, if the join table is changing a lot wouldn't a view have the same performance impact as running a standard query?

Comment: all the considerations done regarding indexes in the answer from OMG Ponies are right and are the first things to consider IMO. One step firther is to use prepared statements that can be done via code or by using views. I am not just saying that using views is the way to achieve better performances. My answer was just a compendium to what OMG Ponies already wrote.